# Question about ICL7673 IC

Tags: resistors

I came across the [ICL7673](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn31/fn3183.pdf) IC used for a battery backup system but I could not understand exactly what is the role of the R2 and R4 resistors in the circuit below (marked with red):
[image]

So my question is: what role does the R2 and R4 resistors have?
When Vp > Vs , P- is high and S- is low and when Vp < Vs, P- is low and S- is high. Since we have the R1 and R3 resistors to bias the base of the PNP transistors, why do we need the R2 and R4 resistors? If somebody could explain this to me (in detail) I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're to prevent the transistors to conduct because of leakage current into the \$P-\$ and \$S-\$ outputs when they're supposed to be off. Any leakage current will go through the resistors and not the emitter-base junction as long as the voltage drop it causes is less than 0.7V.

If it were just the open-drain outputs and their pull-ups to define an output level the leakage would most likely be negligible. But now this current will be amplified by the transistor's \$H_{FE}\$, and that may be too high to be ignored.

**edit**
At high temperatures the output leakage current can go to almost a \$\mu\$A. The transistor may amplify that to more than 100\$\mu\$A from your supply, which you don't want. If we pick a 10k\$\Omega\$ for R2 the leakage current will cause a voltage drop across it (and thus across the transistor's base-emitter junction) of maximum 10mV, which is way too low to get the transistor conducting.

Calculation of R1:
If the main supply is 3V and your equipment needs 100mA you'll need at least 1mA of base current (many [small signal transistors](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC807_BC807W_BC327.pdf) have an \$H_{FE}\$ of at least 100). Let's play safe and go for 5mA base current. Don't forget to check the current through R2: 0.7V/10k\$\Omega\$ = 70\$\mu\$A. OK, that's only 1% so we'll ignore that. Then R1 = (3V - 0.7V)/5mA = 460\$\Omega\$. (Yes, I know, I used other values in my comments, but with the given assumptions these should be better values).

Comment: On of my friends argued that the R2 and R4 resistors act as pull-ups since P- ans S- are open-collector outputs (shown in the functional diagram of the IC) and that without those pull-ups the PNP transistors won't turn on. Is this true? Here is the link with the functinal diagram: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/icl7673functionaldiagra.jpg/

Comment: @Buzai - non quite. In a perfect world R2 and R4 wouldn't be required, while pull-ups are needed to define an output level.

Comment: Buzai It might work without the R pullup to shut it off, but with current gain in PNP and leakage in the IC Drain, dont take a chance that some stray electric field might trigger it. So it adds safety margin to turning it off.. Thats all.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I am really new to this wonderful world of electronics and I am trying to understand things as correctly as possible. So if I understand this correctly R2 and R4 are acting as pull-ups for the open-drain outputs but in the same time R2 and R4 are preventing the PNP transistors to turn on because of the amplified leakage current. Is this correct? Or the pull-ups for the open-drain outputs are in fact R1 and R3? Thank you for your patience with me :).

Comment: @Buzai - R2 and R4 are the pull-ups. They pull the base of the transistors to V+ if the open-drain FETs are off. Leakage in the MOSFETs may pull the base voltage down a little, but if R2 and R4 are small enough (say 1k) the voltage will never be so high that the transistor will start to conduct. R1 and R3 are there to limit the base current when the MOSFETs are on.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I think it is all clear now. One more thing: R2 should have a lower value than R1, right?

Comment: @Buzai - They're independent. R1 sets the base current, which defines the current to your equipment. A 1k resistor will allow a few mA, and with an \$H_{FE}\$ of 100 for the transistor you'll get a few 100mA power supply. R2 can also be 1k. Then even a few 100 uA leakage won't do any harm.

Comment: I thought that R2 must have a smaller value for the following reason: the leakage current flowing to P- and S- would take the path of least resistance. Hence it would go through R2 if it is smaller than R1. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Buzai - it can't go through R2 without first passing R1! The current through R2 is easy to calculate: Vbe/R2, at 1k about 700uA. The current through R1 = (V+ - Vbe)/1k = 4.3mA at a 5V power supply. Then the base current is 4.3mA - 700uA = 3.6mA. If the transistor has an HFE of 100 it will supply up to 360mA to the load.

Comment: Also the leakage current into the PNP transistors counts in this circuit? Or only the leakage current into the MOSFETS count?

Comment: @Buzai - only that of the MOSFET. Leakage current can often be ignored, but the leakage current of the MOSFET gets amplified by the transistor, and then it may become too large to be ignored. The leakage of the transistor is negligible.

Comment: @stevenvh I have one more question: when you are referring to: "it can't go through R2 without first passing R1!" you are considering the electron flow and not the conventional current flow, right?

Comment: @Buzai - No, forget electrons! Always use conventional flow. Look at the schematic. Current flowing from the main supply passing through R2 has only 1 way to get to the P- output: through R1! That's the path the leakage current follows.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand :) (or not ...). One more thing. The leakage current is due to the power supply current or due to the thermal agitation of the charge carriers inside the transistors? If it is due to the power supply (current drew from the power supply), if we would remove R2 and R4 wouldn't that stop the leakage current into P- and S-?

Comment: @Buzai - It's due to the power supply, but removing R2 and R4 wouldn't stop it, because then it would go through the transistor, which would amplify it! That's exactly the reason for R2/R4, so that it doesn't pass through the transistor.

Comment: I think I am confused again (please bear with me). I think I don't really understand what the leakage current is into P-. If the leakage current comes from the supply, with R2 removed, wouldn't the leakage current into P- first go through the PNP transistor? But since P- is off the PNP base is not biased (the base would float) so there should be no flow between the emitter and the base of the PNP? So what path can the leakage current take from the supply, with R2 removed? I am missing something :(.

Comment: @Buzai - The FET should be completely off, but has a high resistance instead, providing a path for current. There will always flow a current if there's a voltage difference and a path. The voltage diff. is between main supply and ground. The path is from main supply via R2, R1 into P-, and via the high resistance of the FET to the IC's ground. Via R2, not via the transistor: R2 causes a voltage drop much too small for the B-E to conduct.

Comment: With R2 in the circuit I think I understand how it works but I don't seem to understand what path could the leakage current have if the R2 would be removed from the circuit and the B-E won't conduct because P- is off :(.

Comment: @Buzai - The current will always find a way. If R2 is not there it will flow through B-E, where it will drop 0.6V instead of the 10mV across R2. Look at the schematic and follow the line. If you can draw it and the current isn't blocked by a diode or so (the transistor's B-E is correctly polarized) there will be a current.

Comment: I think my mistake was that I thought that if R2 is removed from the circuit and P- is off the E-B junction won't conduct at all and there will be no path for the leakage current into P-.

Comment: I have one more question.
I need to signal to a MCU when Vs is active and the load runs from the secondary backup supply.
So I have extended the circuit and connected a GPIO from the MCU to the power supply through a pull-up and in the same time to S-, as shown in the picture from this link: http://imageshack.us/f/832/icl7673new.jpg/
Is this setup ok? Will it affect the leakage current into S-?

Comment: @Buzai - that should work. The I/O pin may have a leakage current up to 1uA, so that adds to the FET's leakage. Use a value between 10k and 100k for the pull-up.

Answer (score 2):

THe IC7673 is an Open Drain ( like Open Collector) driver.  All loads which require pull-up need R to pullup. In this case pullup from the base is more direct and effective than the drain. It also affect the transition time ON to OFF or low to high my making it faster and more reliable.

this in the off state = open drain.

(steven's comments are also true)

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the comments above, I redrew the hysteresis circuit with external PNP transistor for better understanding

[image]